# Firebase Database Query for finding popular items

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase again today. I want to query if an item is popular and if so show it in a tab I've called "Popular" within my app.

```json
{
    "PROMOTED" : true,
    "downvote" : 2,
    "image" : "my image location",
    "station" : "my station name",
    "tag" : "station tagline",
    "upvote" : 10000,
    "url" : "url to station"
}
```

this is an individual item from my Firebase tree. I want to use the child "upvote" to deem if the item is popular. how can I only show items that have an upvote of let's say more than 1000?

This is the code I have so far within my app

```java
ref = db.getReference().child(DATABASE_CHILD);

Query query = ref.orderByChild("upvote");

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Stations_Firebase station_items = new Stations_Firebase();
        station_items.clearArrays();

        for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            station_items = snap.getValue(Stations_Firebase.class);
            String a = station_items.getStation();
            String b = station_items.getTag();
            String c = station_items.getUrl();
            Long d = station_items.getUpvote();
            Long e = station_items.getDownvote();
            String f = station_items.getImage();

            station_items.setArrays(a, b, c, d, e, f);
            station_items.ConvertArrays();
            station_items.SetAdapter(getContext(), mlist);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I only show items that have an upvote or let's say more than 1000?

To get the items that have at least one up-vote, please use the following query:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("upvote").startAt(1);
```

If you want to get the items that have at least 1000 up-votes, please use the following query:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("upvote").startAt(1000);
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data):

- startAt()

> Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I only show items that have an upvote of let's say more than 1000?

```js
Query query = ref.orderByChild('upvote').startAfter(1000);
```

Comment: where is not a valid statement?

Comment: This is the query syntax for Firestore, while OP uses the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase they are completely separate and the API of one does not apply to the other.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen to let me know about that, I might have missed that information while reading the code. I've fixed my answer as per that.